# WP ecommerce – Flow Player not working on product pages

Tags: wordpress, flowplayer

I've got flow player working within Wordpress WP-ecommerce module.

But for some reason the player does not work on the products pages.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out a solution, posting answer as it may help sombody else; It's not exactly what I wanted but it's a good work around;

In the end I used the custom meta fields to list my video name I wanted to show for each product, then within single_product.php I used this peice of code;

```
 <?php if (get_product_meta(wpsc_the_product_id(), 'VIDEO')):?>

           <div id="product-video">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <div id="saiweb_d7d36eec9bb1d23822aaaf221658dd8e" class="flowplayer"></div><script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    WPFP(document).ready(function() {
        //load player
        $f("saiweb_d7d36eec9bb1d23822aaaf221658dd8e", "/wp-content/plugins/word-press-flow-player/flowplayer/gpl/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", {
                plugins: {
                     controls: {                        



                        sliderGradient: 'none',
                        progressGradient: 'medium',





                        backgroundGradient: 'none',
                        bufferGradient: 'none',
                        opacity:1.0
                        }
                },
            clip: {
                    url:'<?php echo "/wp-content/videos/" . get_product_meta(wpsc_the_product_id(), 'VIDEO');?>',
                    autoPlay: false,
                    autoBuffering: false
                },
                canvas: {
                    backgroundColor:''
                }})
            });</script>
            </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```